# Как применять миграции в Laravel (Yii) не отключая сайт?

Tags: php, yii, laravel, миграция

Недавно Laravel LLC представили Envoyer, который позволяет обновлять production сервер не отключая его. И схема там вроде бы как понятна - грубо говоря, мы сначала собираем новую версию в новой папке и, как всё будет готово, переключаем сайт на использование файлов из этой новой папки.

Но я так и не понял, как быть с миграциями. 
Например, у меня есть сервис, в котором пользователи регистрируются по несколько сотен человек в секунду. В сущности пользователя есть поле name (на форме регистрации, соответственно, тоже одно поле), в которое попадает имя и фамилия пользователя.

Я решил обновить это и сделать так, чтобы вместо одного поля name было 2 поля: `first_name` и `last_name` (т. е. новые пользователи при регистрации должны заполнять два соответствующих поля, а поле name уже существующих должно поделиться на два поля). И если с обновлением исходного кода всё понятно, то как быть с обновлением базы? Чтобы не выключать сервер и ни один пользователь не отвалился в процессе регистрации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите без downtime, то делайте изменение структуры в несколько этапов - сначала миграции, которые не ломают ничего в коде, следующей выкладкой код, приспособленный к этой миграции. И так несколько раз, пока не добьетесь нужного результата, причем последовательность выкладки может меняться (сначала код, потом миграции).

Например:

1. Выкладка миграции на добавление двух новых полей.
2. Выкладка кода, который поддерживает эти поля и заполняет и в старое и в новое.
3. Выкладка кода, который не использует старое поле.
4. Выкладка миграции, которая переносит из старого поля в новые данные и удаляет старое поле.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Действительно, по описанному вами сценарию получится обновить без downtime. Делаю для себя вывод, что необходимо продумывать грамотную стратегию обновления сервера.